# Excel VBA Syntax for MouseUp Event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to events and I'm struggling a bit.  Can anyone help me understand why this works:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox3").Object.Text = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value = ""

End Sub
```

But this gives a 'Type mismatch' error at the first line?

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Button = 1
    Shift = 0

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox3").Object.Text = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.  Any introductory references to Events that would help through some of this are appreciated.

Comment: Turn `Option Explicit` on and try to utilize the manuals (F1 help) like [Office development > Office desktop > Office 2013 > Office 2013 shared > Visual Basic for Applications language reference for Office 2013 > Microsoft Forms Visual Basic reference > Reference > Events > MouseDown, MouseUp Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278486(v=office.15).aspx)